Socialite Logged Out the User After Redirect
I have an admin login that is functioning normally for logging in admin users.In the admin panel, there is also a TikTok login page used to obtain the access token for fetching the recent video list. Although it is called a login page, it doesn't store user information. It only stores the access token in a JSON file.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class TiktokLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('tiktok')->scopes(['user.info.basic', 'video.list'])->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        try {
            $tiktokUser = Socialite::driver('tiktok')->stateless()->user();

            $filePath = 'tiktok-token.json';

            $tokenData = [
                'access_token' => $tiktokUser->token,
                'expires_in' => $tiktokUser->expiresIn,
                'refresh_token' => $tiktokUser->refreshToken,
            ];

            Storage::put($filePath, json_encode($tokenData));

            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error during TikTok callback:', [
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ]);

            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN)->withErrors(['error' => 'Unable to connect with TikTok.']);
        }
    }
}


As the redirect runs, the user is logged out and sent to the admin login page. How can I prevent the user from being logged out?
I already checked auth()->user() before and after the TikTok process, and it seems that the user is logged out after redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN). Is this issue related to something specific with Socialite? Is there a way to keep the user logged in?
